# Kick an user from telegram chat with nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using that [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/api.md) library and I need to handle users in my group.
When the subscription is expired, I need to kick the user. At the moment I use https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#kickchatmember. In that Way, I ban that user, and for re-add to my group I need to unbanChat and invite with Chat link, I can't re-add without that link.

Is it possible to kick the user without Ban?
I see that I can use `exportChatInviteLink` method to generate link, but I can Revoked that link after click?